# AHK Trouble getting my image to show when pressing GUI

Tags: autohotkey

I've been editing a code to make it more personal and can't seem to get the %crsLocation% image to open with it. The button presses, but nothing else happens. I have tried directly connecting the directory to no prevail. I'm not sure what else to do. I am still kinda new to AHK and besides some basic classes in college and Codecademy my knowledge is still limited.
I was wondering if anyone could see what I am doing wrong

```
#NoEnv
#SingleInstance Force

SetBatchLines, -1

SetWorkingDir, A_ScriptDir

; GUI Design
Gui Show, x600 y325 w481 h381, CrossHair Overlay
Gui, Color, Gray
Gui, Font, Caqua

; GUI Buttons
Gui Add, Button, vCrosshair gCrosshair Default w80, Crosshair
Gui Add, Button, vReload gReload Default w80, Reload
Gui Add, Button, vExit gExit Default w80, Exit

Return

; Labels
Reload:
    Reload
    return

Exit:
    ExitApp
    return

Crosshair:
    If _Crosshair := ! _Crosshair
        Loop
        {
            ;Config
            crsLocation := "crosshairdot.png"
            crsHeight := "7"
            crsWidth := "7"
            invsColor := "ffffff"
            locCompensator  := "4"
            locX        := "960"
            loxY        := "540"
            ;End of config

            diflocX := locX - locCompensator
            diflocY := locY - locCompensator
            setCross = 0

            ~XButton2:: 
                if (setCross = 0) {
                    Gui, chscript: New
                    Gui, Add, Picture, x0 y0 h%crsHeight% w%crsWidth%, %crsLocation%
                    Gui +LastFound +AlwaysOnTop -Caption +ToolWindow +E0x00000020
                    Gui, Show, x%diflocX% y%diflocY% h%crsHeight% w%crsWidth%

                    ; Middle of Screen = 960 540
                    Gui, Color,  %invsColor%
                    WinSet, TransColor, %invsColor%

                    setCross = 1;
                }
                else {
                    Gui, chscript: Destroy
                    setCross = 0
                }
                Return
            }
            Return
        Return
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all in the documents it states scriptdir with percents around it, even though it works without signs I'd stick with docs suggestions,

```
SetWorkingDir, %A_ScriptDir%
```

and then there is this typo,

```
loxY        := "540"
```

should be **locY** I belive